# Aligning a div in the middle of other divs and anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have written the following HTML/CSS and now going tumbletweend adjusting the *UV Index*

```
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
<div class="well" id="container1">
<button  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="togOutBtn">Hide Outdoors</button>
<fieldset class="outdoor" style="display: none;">
  <legend id="location">Loading.</legend>

  <a href="#" onclick="waterPlant1()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle"><i class="fa"><br>Water<br>the<br>plant</i></a>
    <div id="uvIndex" style="width:300px; margin:0 auto;" class="divTableHead">UV Index</div>
  <div id="Outtemp" class="label label-primary"></div><br>
  <div id="Outhumid" class="label label-default"></div><br>
  <div id="dewPoint" class="label label-primary"></div><br>
  <div id="OutheadIndex" class="label label-default"></div>
```

which is resulting in

[image]

what I want is the UV index div in the middle align of divs that are shown bottom left blue-grey and anchor tag on right.

Comment: Take off the `margin: 0 auto` from that div. That's what's causing it to center itself.

Comment: Do you want to align the UV Index block to left or other elements to center? You can create a simple fiddle for better understanding and even quick responses as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a big div containing the info and use ' *display: inline;* ' to the big div and the UV div:

```
<div id="infodiv" style="display:inline;">
   <div id="Outtemp" class="label label-primary"></div><br>
   <div id="Outhumid" class="label label-default"></div><br>
   <div id="dewPoint" class="label label-primary"></div><br>
   <div id="OutheadIndex" class="label label-default"></div>
</div>
<div id="uvIndex" style="display:inline; width:300px; margin:0 auto;" class="divTableHead">UV Index</div>
```

Comment: What about circle button "water the plant" ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Same thing, apply display:inline; also to it.

Answer (score 0):

I find this as convenient solution:

```
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
<div class="well" id="container1">
<button  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="togOutBtn">Hide Outdoors</button>
<fieldset class="outdoor" style="display: none;">
  <legend id="location">Loading.</legend>
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr style="vertical-align:top;">
      <td>
         <div id="Outtemp" class="label label-primary"></div><br>
  <div id="Outhumid" class="label label-default"></div><br>
  <div id="dewPoint" class="label label-primary"></div><br>
  <div id="OutheadIndex" class="label label-default"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="uvIndex">Loading UV index.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
          <a href="#" onclick="waterPlant1()" class="btn btn-default btn-circle"><i class="fa"><br>Water<br>the<br>plant</i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Not sure why web world is moving away form tables.